# jQuery calling php script onload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery's ajax to call a php script onload.  This script will return xml from a url web service, parse through it, and then display bits and pieces of it into a div tag when the page loads (onload).  I'm okay with php when it comes to using forms, but getting php scripts to run onload is not working for me.  Could someone please look through my code and give me your advice?  Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Word of the Day</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

<h3>Word of the Day: </h3>
<div id="word_day"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).load(function() {


    $.ajax({
      post: "GET",
      url: "word_day.php"
    }).done(function() {
      alert(this.responseText);
    }).fail(function() {
      alert(this.responseText);
    });


  });

});
```

I did not add my PHP code since I was pretty sure that it wasn't the cause of my frustration.

Comment: Are the done or fail events being triggered?

Comment: The "done" event was being triggered if I replace "this.responseText" with strings like successful or failure, but entering "this.responseText" produces undefined.

Comment: does word_day.php exist in your web root?

Comment: yes.  All of these files exist & are placed within the same folder.

Comment: have you placed a breakpoint in your browser debugger to check what variables are accessible in both the .done and .fail?

Comment: No.  I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need those two handlers, just one:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        post: "GET",
        url: "word_day.php"
    }).done(function() 
    {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }).fail(function() 
    {
        alert(this.responseText);
    });

});
```

As you had it you were trying to create one handler when the handler fired which was never going to work.

**Edit:**

Your done/fail part should look like:

```
}).done(function(data) 
{
    alert(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm still getting undefined.  I'm guessing that I'm not supposed to be using this.responseText.

Comment: Awesome!  it worked.  Could you help me understand why I had to add these parameters to make it work?

Comment: That's the way jQuery works. It passes the received data to your supplied function if it succeeds (you can call the parameter anything you like). The same goes for `fail`. It's expecting your function parameters to receive the values it has, you didn't have those and was trying to access them via `this.responseText` which, as you found, is not valid.

Read up on it at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/